# Collapsing rows in a Pandas dataframe if all rows have only one value in their columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have following DF

```
         col1  |  col2   | col3   | col4   | col5  | col6
    0    -     |   15.0  |  -     |  -     |   -   |  -
    1    -     |   -     |  -     |  -     |   -   |  US
    2    -     |   -     |  -     |  Large |   -   |  -
    3    ABC1  |   -     |  -     |  -     |   -   |  -
    4    -     |   -     |  24RA  |  -     |   -   |  -
    5    -     |   -     |  -     |  -     |   345 |  -
```

I want to collapse rows into one as follows

```
    output DF:
         col1  |  col2    | col3   | col4   | col5  | col6
    0    ABC1  |   15.0   |  24RA  |  Large |   345 |  US
```

I do not want to iterate over columns but want to use pandas to achieve this.

Comment: What are the other values beside the valid one, a literal dash(*-*)? or `NaN`?

Comment: its **NaN** - My bad, for pretty print I replaced it '-'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 0**
*Super Simple*

```
pd.concat([pd.Series(df[c].dropna().values, name=c) for c in df], axis=1)

   col1  col2  col3   col4   col5 col6
0  ABC1  15.0  24RA  Large  345.0   US
```

---

*Can we handle more than one value per column?*
*Sure we can!*

```
df.loc[2, 'col3'] = 'Test'

   col1  col2  col3   col4   col5 col6
0  ABC1  15.0  Test  Large  345.0   US
1   NaN   NaN  24RA    NaN    NaN  NaN
```

**Option 1**
*Generalized solution using `np.where` like a surgeon*

```
v = df.values
i, j = np.where(np.isnan(v))

s = pd.Series(v[i, j], df.columns[j])

c = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
s.index = [c, s.index]
s.unstack(fill_value='-')  # <-- don't fill to get NaN

   col1  col2  col3   col4 col5 col6
0  ABC1  15.0  24RA  Large  345   US
```

---

```
df.loc[2, 'col3'] = 'Test'

v = df.values
i, j = np.where(np.isnan(v))

s = pd.Series(v[i, j], df.columns[j])

c = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
s.index = [c, s.index]
s.unstack(fill_value='-')  # <-- don't fill to get NaN

   col1  col2  col3   col4 col5 col6
0  ABC1  15.0  Test  Large  345   US
1     -     -  24RA      -    -    -
```

---

**Option 2**
*`mask` to make nulls then `stack` to get rid of them*

Or we could have

```
# This should work even if `'-'` are NaN
# but you can skip the `.mask(df == '-')`
s = df.mask(df == '-').stack().reset_index(0, drop=True)
c = s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
s.index = [c, s.index]
s.unstack(fill_value='-')

   col1  col2  col3   col4 col5 col6
0  ABC1  15.0  Test  Large  345   US
1     -     -  24RA      -    -    -
```

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. For simplicity (pretty print) I removed NaN with '-' in actual dataframe its NaN.

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared. I liked the super simple one as I know that my DF will have only one values in each row. It works.

Comment: it frustrates me that you can't just do `df.max()` ... i guess this would be fiddly to implement though might require a change to numpy\

Comment: What if I want to collapse only those columns which has single value and keep others as is? I can slice out those columns, run the above collapse method then join with remaining columns.
Is there a better way like above 'super simple'?

Comment: i've added another option which might work well if you just want to fill in the values in your columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max`, but you need to convert the null values in the string-valued columsn (which is a bit ugly unfortunately)

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[np.nan, "ABC1"], 'col2':[15.0, np.nan]})

>>> df.apply(lambda c: c.fillna('') if c.dtype is np.dtype('O') else c).max()
col1    ABC1
col2      15
dtype: object
```

You could also you a combination of backfill and forwardfill to fill in the gaps, this could be useful if only want to apply this to some of your columns:

```
>>> df.apply(lambda c: c.fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill'))
```