# merge nested lists into one by replacing the null value python

Tags: python

I have a list with several nested lists inside, here is the sample:

```
temp_lst = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '51', '51', '19'],
            [None, None, None, '55', '55', '55', '55', None, None, None],
            ['23', '23', '55', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

I want to merge it into just one list, and the value should be in a specific order, the result needs to be **exactly like this**:

```
           ['23', '23', '55', '55', '55', '55', '55', '51', '51', '19']
```

There could be more lists inside `temp_lst`.

Comment: Could you show us an attempt made by you in order to solve this ?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Collapsing rows in a Pandas dataframe if all rows have only one value in their columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44319649/7851470)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really flattening your list, but instead you take from each position inside the sublists the value thats not `None`.

You can combine your lists positionally by using [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and use `or` to get the value that not `None` (or `''` - wich you have none of):

```
# you keep the vaue on each position thats not None 
data =  [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '51', '51', '19'],
         [None, None, None, '55', '55', '55', '55', None, None, None],
         ['23', '23', '55', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
# wanted ['23', '23', '55', '55', '55', '55', '55', '51', '51', '19']

def coalesque(iterable, default):
    """Returns the first truthy value from iterable or default."""
    for x in iterable:
        if x: 
            return x
    return default

result = [ coalesque(n,'') for n in zip(*data)]  

print(result)
```

will output:

```
['23', '23', '55', '55', '55', '55', '55', '51', '51', '19']
```

This works as long as you can ensure that:

- all lists are of equal lenght (else research itertools.zip_longest)
- there is only ever 1 element not `None` per "column" (only 1st one is used)

---

Use the `default` for `coalesque(iterable,default)` to define what should be returned if all values are falsy in one "column".

See:

- [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
- [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) for unevenly sized lists

Answer (score 2):

You need to transpose your matrix and then filter out possible candidates .

```
arr=[[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '51', '51', '19'],
 [ None, None, None,'55', '55', '55', '55', None, None, None],
['23', '23', '55',None, None, None,None, None, None,None]]

ans=[]
for i in zip(*arr[::-1]):
    ans.append(list(filter(lambda x:x is not None, i))[0])
print(ans)
```

Comment: its a bit wasteful to create a list from a filter and select the 1st element of it, it will crash if one column has only `None` in it. Reversing the input list is also not needed - with that in mind `for i in zip(*arr):  ans.append(filter(lambda x:x is not None, i)[0])` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_list = [n for sublist in original_list for n in sublist if n != None]
```

basically what I do here is use list comprehensions.

Comment: thank you for this suggestion, but i want to keep the values in the same position. like the result listed, 23 should be the first one in the final list .

Comment: Just invert the list with `my_list[::-1]` then

Comment: Its not a "flatten" probelm - solution takes the not-`None` value on each list position and keeps that, the Nones are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

While others have posted one liners, here is a recursive function that will work if there are more layers in your list.

```
def unstack_list(temp_list):
    # Construct list of elements to return
    answer = []
    for i in temp_list:
        # if element of list is list, recurse and concatenate lists
        if type(i) == list:
            answer = unstack_list(i) + answer
        # add to list if not None
        elif i is not None:
            answer.append(i)
    return answer
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the result is ['51', '51', '19', '23', '23', '55', '55', '55', '55', '55'], not in the order listed. and the 'typeof' should be changed to 'type'

Comment: Sorry - fixed it for you; basically since you want the reverse order, you can either flip the way the constructed list is concatenated, or reverse the initial list instead.

Comment: but this is just one example, other cases could be in different orders which i can't just simply flip it

Comment: Can we assume that each list is either a list of lists OR a list of values? And there won't be a list containing both lists and values? I understand what you mean by the question now, but your initial question was very poorly worded. Can we also assume that there are no overlaps of values in each position? i.e. that [[None, 1], [None, 2]] won't happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to do this.
With Numpy you flatten a list of any dimensions

```
import numpy as np
a  = [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '51', '51', '19'],
 [ None, None, None,'55', '55', '55', '55', None, None, None],
['23', '23', '55',None, None, None,None, None, None,None]]
a = np.array(a) # Converting to numpy array
a = a.flatten() # Flatten a list with numpy's builtin function
a = [i for i in a if i != None] # Removing all occurences of None
a = list(a) # Converting back to python list
```

By, this you can flatten a list of any dimensions

Comment: Its not a "flatten" probelm - solution takes the not-`None` value on each list position and keeps that, the Nones are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This solution keeps the last non-None value of each row, and skips any position showing all None values.

```
def crunchnones(data):
"""
Assumes data is an iterable containing lists of values, and
    returns a single list of all non-None value in all lists in data,
    maintaining their positions inside each list.
If no list contain a non-None value in a given position, that position
    will be silently skipped.
If more than one list contains a non-None value in a given position,
    only the one in the last list will be returned.

Example:
>>> data =  [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '51', '51', '19'],
             [None, None, None, '55', '55', '55', '55', None, None, None],
             ['23', '23', '55', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
>>> data2 =  [[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '51', None, '19'],
              [None, None, None, '55', '55', '55', '55', None, None, None],
              [None, '23', '55', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
>>> data3 =  [['21', None, None, None, None, None, None, '51', '51', '19'],
              ['22', None, None, '55', '55', '55', '55', None, None, None],
              ['23', '23', '55', None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]

>>>crunchnones(data)
['23', '23', '55', '55', '55', '55', '55', '51', '51', '19']
>>>crunchnones(data2)
['23', '55', '55', '55', '55', '55', '51', '19']
>>>crunchnones(data3)
['23', '23', '55', '55', '55', '55', '55', '51', '51', '19']
>>>
"""
#
temp = {}
for riga in data:
    temp.update({i: x for i, x in enumerate(riga) if x is not None})
return [temp[i] for i in sorted(temp)]
```